# What is the difference between SERIAL and AUTO_INCREMENT in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have come across two ways to increment the ids in mysql automatically.

One is **SERIAL** and other is **AUTOINCREMENT**.

So Suppose i want to create a table myfriends.
I can create it in two ways like:

1)

```
mysql> create table myfriends(id int primary key auto_increment,frnd_name varchar(50) not null);
```

2)

```
mysql> create table myfriends(id serial primary key,frnd_name varchar(50) not null);
```

What is difference between the two ?

OR

Do anyone way has advantages over other ?

Please Help.

Comment: as a bonus, take a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/mysql-why-is-auto-increment-limited-to-just-primary-keys

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html)

> SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.

So, be careful when creating a reference to a SERIAL PK, since that reference column has to be of this exact type.

Answer (score 19):

**`AUTO_INCREMENT`** is an *attribute* of a specific column of any numeric type (int or float), both signed and unsigned. When rows are inserted it automatically assigns sequential numbers, so you don't have to (e.g. by using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

**`SERIAL`** is an *alias* that combines column type casting (`BIGINT` specifically), `AUTO_INCREMENT`, `UNSIGNED` and other *attributes* for a specific column (see quote from docs below). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html

> SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.
>
> SERIAL DEFAULT VALUE in the definition of an integer column is an alias for NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.

Answer (score 3):

From [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

> SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.
>
> SERIAL DEFAULT VALUE in the definition of an integer column is an
>   alias for NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.

If no value is specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign NULL or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers. MySQL doesn't automatically decrease the autoincrement value when you delete a row. Reasons are:

- Danger of broken data integrity (imagine multiple users perform
  deletes or inserts...doubled entries may occur or worse)
- Errors may occur when you use master slave replication or
  transactions