# mysql copying specific columns from one database table to another using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a cron job through php that has mysql queries (NOT for backup purposes), and want it to copy two specific columns from a table from one database to another (the two databases are on the same server, but has different connections).

I've tried

```
    insert into newDB.your_table select * from oldDB.your_table;
```

but that didn't work for some reason and i want it to be specific to 2 columns only.

Any help, code, example, tutorial would be much much appreciated.

Thank you for time.

Comment: That SQL looks good.  Your problem appears to lie elsewhere.  Can you run this query successfully from the command line, or WorkBench, or whatever you use?  Oh, also, I believe the two tables would have to have the same number of columns, of the same datatypes, as well, for this query to work.

Comment: well it showed through the command line that it was successful but nothing is showing up in the database, plus, i don't want o copy all data, only 2 columns. Also the two databases have different number of columns but same datatypes.

Comment: To copy only specific columns, refer to my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown on this page  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

To selectively copy only specific columns from one table to another, the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

So for your example:
    `INSERT INTO newDB.some_table (id, value) SELECT id, value FROM oldDB.some_other_table;`

Comment: but the table i'm copying to is on another database, not the same one.

Comment: Please avoid using w3schools and instead link directly to the current-version MySQL documentation whenever possible. The canonical source is often the most up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you for help, it worked,  but now its forming duplicates, how can i prevent that ? and as i mentioned, its for a cron job, so in this case there will be a lot of duplicates

Comment: lol...yes, it will create duplicates if you continually select *.  I think perhaps you might do yourself a favor by including more information in your question.

Comment: hhm....well, i'm copying username & password columns and also the column where shows if the user is active or not, from the membership system database to the external application database, so when if there is a duplicate it would update it accordingly. I think I should be using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (activefield = '1')`

Comment: That will work if you have a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE KEY` defined, according to:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Please bare with me, if i don't have Primary or Unique Key, how can i solve this issue? or whats the best practice? shall i add `IGNORE` after `INSERT` ?

Comment: If you're tracking users (or really doing anything), it is best practice to declare a `PRIMARY KEY`, which is almost always an auto incrementing integer.  I read a tip recently, which suggested using a `SERIAL KEY`, which just easily creates an auto incrementing, unsigned `BIGINT`.  The unique id is really useful...for lots of stuff.  Like differentiating between users to track their states ;)     Read about `SERIAL` here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021983/what-is-the-difference-between-serial-and-auto-increment-in-mysql