# MySql strange behaviour - strips characters from right of id in where clause

Tags: mysql

I noticed something strange today. Say you have a mysql table:

```
create table usr(
  usr_id serial
)
```

And you insert a row:

```
INSERT INTO usr (usr_id) VALUES ('1');
```

And then you run a query:

```
SELECT * FROM usr WHERE usr_id='1sfgfsdgs'
```

MySql returns the result as if you had entered:

```
SELECT * FROM usr WHERE usr_id='1'
```

Should this happen?? If yes - can someone point me to the documentation describing this? I'm just curious as to whether this is expected behaviour.

[jeremy@jjxps15 ~]$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: the integer of 1sfgfsdgs is 1, maybe that is why. Is the usr_id fleld defined as an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the page that has the dirt, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

But it's clear as mud

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type
>   conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions
>   occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to
>   strings as necessary, and vice versa.

It does have a few examples that makes things a bit clearer

```
mysql> SELECT 1 > '6x';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT 7 > '6x';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT 0 > 'x6';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT 0 = 'x6';
        -> 1
```

What this essentially means is that if a number is compared to an alpha numeric string and that string starts with a number all non numeric characters towards the end are discarded.

The fact that you use serial doesn't really have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Because `usr_id` is a `serial` column, it may only contain integers ([What is the difference between SERIAL and AUTO_INCREMENT in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021983/what-is-the-difference-between-serial-and-auto-increment-in-mysql#20022067)).

MySQL therefore ignores the characters beside the '1'.