# MySQL 'NOT NULL' Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question about 'NOT NULL' error. I need to make a table with variable type: 'SERIAL' and length of 7. Here is an error that SQL sends to me:

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE  `table42`.`CheckOuts ` (
      `CheckOutID` SERIAL( 7 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

The error that is returned:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(7) NOT NULL) ENGINE = MyISAM' at line 1

Comment: Serial is already `not null`

Comment: [Check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20022067/801544)

Comment: [See the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html), `SERIAL` is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`

Comment: Try to avoid using MyISAM whenever possible. It's a creaky old engine that lacks many of the features in InnoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that `SERIAL` isn't supported in that method for MySQL.  Docs suggest you should be using `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead:

see: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/auto_increment

also: [What is the difference between SERIAL and AUTO_INCREMENT in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021983/what-is-the-difference-between-serial-and-auto-increment-in-mysql)

These suggest you should be creating your table with the following example syntax:

```
  create table myfriends (
      id int primary key auto_increment,
      frnd_name varchar(50) not null
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

The SERIAL type already has NOT NULL as part of its definition, so your NOT NULL declaration is redundant

Answer (score 1):

Error is not due to `NOT NULL`, although `SERIAL` already includes `NOT NULL`, an error does not occur when duplicating it. The cause of the error is for the length that you try to assign `(7)`:

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CheckOuts`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CheckOuts` (
    ->   -- `CheckOutID` SERIAL(7) NOT NULL
    ->   `CheckOutID` SERIAL NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=MYISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `CheckOuts`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: CheckOuts
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `CheckOuts` (
  `CheckOutID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UNIQUE KEY `CheckOutID` (`CheckOutID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't understand what you're trying to do, but if you need to assign a length, you'll need something like:

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CheckOuts`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CheckOuts` (
    ->   `CheckOutID` INT(7) UNSIGNED SERIAL DEFAULT VALUE
    -> ) ENGINE=MYISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `CheckOuts`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: CheckOuts
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `CheckOuts` (
  `CheckOutID` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UNIQUE KEY `CheckOutID` (`CheckOutID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See documentation:

> [11.1.1 Numeric Type Overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html)
>
> ...
>
> **SERIAL** is an alias for **BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
>   UNIQUE**.
>
> **SERIAL DEFAULT VALUE** in the definition of an integer column is an
>   alias for **NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE**.
>
> ...