# How to create table with foreign keys in cloud shell?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Hi I'm trying to create a table in mysql database in google cloud sql which I succeed.

My problem is to create tables with more than one foreign key- i tried and got error.

my syntax was:

```
CREATE TABLE images
```

```
CREATE TABLE images_tbl (
url TEXT,
categoryId NUMERIC,
userId NUMERIC,
beginIndex INT,
endIndex INT,
imageId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
CONSTRAINT FK_CATEGORYIMAGE FOREIGN KEY (categoryId) REFERENCES categories_tbl(categoryId), 
CONSTRAINTS FK_USERIMAGE FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(UserId));
```

the error was:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE images_tbl (url TEXT,categoryId NUMERIC,userId NUMERIC,beginIndex I' at line 1.
```

I cant find material in the internet. Please be good people and help me as fast as possible- this is an application about production!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you spelled "CONSTRAINT" wrong for your second foreign key. Can you try:

```
CREATE TABLE images_tbl (
url TEXT,
categoryId NUMERIC,
userId NUMERIC,
beginIndex INT,
endIndex INT,
imageId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
CONSTRAINT FK_CATEGORYIMAGE FOREIGN KEY (categoryId) REFERENCES categories_tbl(categoryId), 
CONSTRAINT FK_USERIMAGE FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(UserId));
```

You also need to make sure that categoryId and userId are type `NUMERIC` in your `categories_tbl` table and `users` table. The categoryId and userId columns must also be `PRIMARY KEY` in those tables as well.

Comment: I TRIED YOUR SUGGESTION, AND NOW THIS IS THE ERROR:
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: @riki I've updated my answer with some more information, please make sure those extra steps are followed.

Comment: thank you! categoryId and UserId are SERIAL PRIMARY KEY. maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Yeah potentially, have a read of this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20022067/7429535

Is it working now?

Comment: @riki I've just spotted that in ```images_tbl```, you've declared the ```UserId``` column as ```userId``` (Lower case "U"). Please change that to ```UserId``` and let me know how you get on.

Comment: you know how to set column to identity and numeric datatype?

Comment: If you're talking about the ```UserId``` in the ```users``` table, use this:

```ALTER TABLE users CHANGE `userId` `identity` NUMERIC;```